# How to keep chosen files when building with electron

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I need to keep some files (like my data.db file) when installing electron app, I can copy and paste it after installation of `.exe`, but is better to have it by default.
Is the a way to configure electron builder to keep files or directories after installation in the installation path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using the **extraFiles** option: https://www.electron.build/configuration/contents#extrafiles

Comment: using extraFile to include a whole folder: "extraFiles": [
      "YOUR_FOLDER/**"
    ],

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep certain folders when updating an Electron app, you can use the asarUnpack field in the app's package.json file. The asarUnpack field specifies a list of glob patterns that match the files and directories that should be unpacked when the app is packaged as an ASAR (Atom Shell Archive).

For example, to keep the assets and node_modules directories when updating the app, you can add the following lines to the package.json file:

```
"asarUnpack": [
  "assets/*",
  "node_modules/*"
]
```

This will cause the assets and node_modules directories to be extracted to a separate folder when the app is packaged, and they will not be overwritten when the app is updated.

Note that the asarUnpack field is only used when packaging the app as an ASAR. If you are not using ASAR packaging, you can use a different approach to preserve certain directories during updates.